# Archlinux ARM Apache server fails to start

Tags: apache-httpd, openssl, socket, https

I am currently setting up an Apache web server on my Pi running on Archlinux ARM.
After installing and making the first small configurations I have tested it and it works. Then I stop the server and wanted to add SSL certificates, I have followed this [guide](http://linuxconfig.org/apache-web-server-ssl-authentication). But after doing this the server does not start again. The error message I get from *systemctl status httpd.service* is:

```
httpd.service - Apache Web Server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service:disabled)
Active: failed (Result: resources) since Di [...]; 13 min ago
Process: 1071 ExecStart=/usr/bin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

[...] apachectl[1071]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock:could not bind to address [::]443
[...] PID file /run/httpd/htppd.pit not readable (yet?) after start
[...] httpd.service never wrote its PID file. Failing.
[...] Failed to start Apache Web Server
[...] Unit httpd.service entered failed state
```

The [...] brackets indicates where the date and time would be showned, I left them out as I had to retype everything.
I have already change the content of the file */usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/apache.conf* to:

```
d /run/httpd 0755 http http -
```

I have also checked if there is another service running with the following command:

```
/usr/sbin/lsof -i | grep http
```

But there is no and chaning the listening port to e.g. 8080 produces the same error just with port 8080 instead of 443.

I am looking forward to hear from you.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the PID as the error says:

> httpd.service never wrote its PID file. Failing.

The name off the pid file is unusual

```
/run/httpd/htppd.pit
```

Shouldn't it be /run/httpd/htppd.pid ?

Also check that /run/httpd/ is owned by the same user as the httpd deamon runs under.
Or at least that this user is given permission to write to /run/httpd/ folder.